# Boot error: mount: special device /dev/sdax does not exist

Tags: boot, sd-card, boot-issues, mount

I mount the SD card on boot with the following line in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /media/USB_OC > /home/pi/logs/USB_mount_log 2>&1
```

This was working perfectly until an `apt-get upgrade` and now it fails with:

```
mount: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist
```

This line still works manually however.  So I've added `sleep 10` above it in `rc.local`, and now it mounts ok on boot.  But I'm a bit uneasy implementing hacky workarounds like this without understanding the underlying cause.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not just add a `fstab` entry like everyone else.

Comment: How long ago was the *previous* time you ran `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Just yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is custom init script and commands added here are run at boot-time. Nothing guarantee at that time your peripheral devices were properly powered up before your `mount` command get execute. And the hack `sleep 10` is a proof.

I suggest you should mount your card at boot with `/etc/fstab` instead.

Comment: there's also no guarantee (not 100% anyway) that the device will always be /dev/sda - for example add another USB drive and reboot ... if you must use fstab, "real" admins use `UUID=....`

Comment: yes, at least use LABEL to differentiate devices in 'fstab', I personally use UUID too :)